# Nextjs with firebase auth and next-auth - Auth is null

Tags: javascript, next.js, firebase-authentication, next-auth

I'm building a website with nextjs 13 (app router) and firebase.
Saw people recommending to use next-auth and firebase auth together if I wanted to use firebase auth.
So I setup my firebase

I have this config for firebase:

```
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebase_app = getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApps()[0];
const auth = getAuth(firebase_app);
export { firebase_app, auth }
```

Problem is: I can signin but when I try to use auth from firebase it returns null/undefined

My code to update password:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { EmailAuthProvider, updatePassword, reauthenticateWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth} from '@/firebase/config'

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const res = await request.formData()
    const old_password = res.get('old-password')?.toString()
    const new_password = res.get('new-password')?.toString()
    const confirm_password = res.get('confirm-password')?.toString()
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    console.log("user: ", user)

    if(!old_password || !new_password || !confirm_password) {
        return NextResponse.json({ status: 400, statusText: "Missing info" })
    }
    else if(new_password !== confirm_password) {
        return NextResponse.json({ status: 400, statusText: "Passwords do not match" })
    }

    if(user != null){
        const userEmail = user.email || "";
        const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(userEmail, old_password);

        reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential).then(() => {
            // User re-authenticated.
            updatePassword(user, new_password).then(() => {
                // Update successful.
                return NextResponse.json({ status: 200, statusText: "Password updated" })
              }).catch((error) => {
                // An error ocurred
                return NextResponse.json({ status: 500, statusText: "Error updating password" })
              });
          }).catch((error) => {
            // An error ocurred
            if(error.code === "auth/wrong-password"){
                throw new Error("wrong-password");
            }
            else{
                throw new Error("error-reauthenticating");
            }
            //return NextResponse.json({ status: 401, statusText: "Incorrect password" })
        });
    }
    else{
        // If not logged in, redirect to login page
        return NextResponse.json({ status: 401, statusText: "Not logged in" })
    } 
}
```

Should I stop using next-auth? Or is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

this is expected behavior because firebase need time to validate if token is really correct so getAuth() always return null on startup you should use `onAuthStateChanged` to track when firebase authentication complete wall

Comment: is it possible to use `onAuthStateChanged` in route handlers? I try it but since it is an observer it will just pass by it and return (expected - but I don't see how to solve it)

Comment: i don't think that is possible directly but you can save auth as a react variable and try to react it